# Open email client with the JFreeChart's chart (image) pasted in the body

Tags: java, image, swing, email, jfreechart

I want to have an "Email" button which would open the default email client and would paste the JFreeChart image in the email body. I know that this could be done by copying the image (Chart) and pasting it in the email client. However, I want this to be done on the click of the button. I can use the `Desktop.getDesktop().mail(...)` for opening the email client but the other requirement of pasting the image remains puzzling for me. Can this be accomplished?

Comment: If you can get an image from the chart, this ceases to have anything meaningful to do with JFreeChart itself.  Send a plain image from your app., and you can likely do it with the chart image.

Answer (score 2):

How big (in bytes) will the images typically be?  You can include it in an HTML based email embedded as a [Data URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) image.  But that has size limits in some older browsers, not sure of email clients.

Safer would be to send a [Multipart message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages).

Comment: This should work with any of the [`ChartUtilities.writeChartAsXxx(OutputStream out, …)`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartUtilities.html).